# Building error: Indigo on Debian Jessie: pluginlib "undefined reference to..."

Tags: ros, boost, debian, jessie, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am currently trying to build ROS indigo from source on my Debian Jessie machine. I keep on getting the following error when the process is trying to build the package "pluginlib". I am really stuck here and would appreciate your help on this!

Thanks!

```
Linking CXX executable /home/tman/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pluginlib/lib/pluginlib/plugin_tool
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > > const&)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/plugin_tool.dir/build.make:116: recipe for target '/home/tman/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pluginlib/lib/pluginlib/plugin_tool' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/tman/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pluginlib/lib/pluginlib/plugin_tool] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:310: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/plugin_tool.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/plugin_tool.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'pluginlib': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/tman/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pluginlib && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226224/building-error:-indigo-on-debian-jessie:-pluginlib-%22undefined-reference-to...%22/) by [tomtana](https://answers.ros.org/users/25903/tomtana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2019-02-05**:
it's not a dependencies problem on Debian Stretch and ROS Lunar. The command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro lunar -y -r --os=debian:stretch` doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was caused by unresolved dependencies.

I could resolve them by running the command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:jessie
```

---

Originally posted by [tomtana](https://answers.ros.org/users/25903/tomtana/) with karma: 36 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0